# Power BI DAX Cannot display correct monthly of last year's figures in a Matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "strange" problem in visualizing the values of the "last" year (that is the most current year with data of a full year). In the example delivered it is 2019 which holds the bookings facts. The year should be derived by a related table (LetztesVollesJahrDim) that holds a min/max date and year value for each company/entity. The DateDim table holds all dates and is configured to be the Date dimension.

The relations are shown in the graphic below.

I created a Report that should display different matrix tables with different values:

- one, that shows the last full year's monthly values by Cost Center (which works correct)
- one, that shows all years monthly values including an estimated value for the current year (2020) (which also works correct)
- one, that could drill down to the details level of the Facts and display the figures per month (in columns) of the last full year (i.e. 2019) putting the Cost Center and other groups down the most detailed level into rows. This Matrix makes use of Calculated Measures created with Tabular Editor.

At this point I can here you say... try it without the Calculated measures and indeed I did that by simply displaying a Card that got a Visual Filter to DateDim[M]=7 to simulate the appliance of each matrix's column. Problem is the same: The Month filter of the Visual (or within the Calculated Measure) is ignored and the yearly sum is displayed (~48k) which is wrong.

As I am currently an Expert in SQL Server DBMS but not in the Architecture of Power BI's DAX Models I am not truely aware about the consequences when and why filters are removed, ignored, overwritten or added at which level of modeling.

Originally I tried to create a simple Calculated Measure that reflects the last full year of the company. That works, but its usage in the huge Matrix was impossible as it was calculating forever. That's why I created the simple table "LetztesVollesJahrDim" to hold a persisted value for each company.

The idea is simple: Create a Query that inner joins these tables and display the Sum for each month [M] like this:

Fact[Turnover] - Fact[CompanyKey] -> CompanyDim[CompanyKey] <-> LastFullYear[CompanyKey] - LastFullYear[MostCurrentYear] -> DateDim[Y] - DateDim[DateKey] -> Fact[StapleDateKey]

So, what is the Problem?

I tried a couple of DAX queries and all come up with a different wrong value.

Following three different approaches for a Calculated Measure "Sum LY":

1.

Σ LY = CALCULATE(SUM(KontobuchungenFact[UmsatzNegiert]), DATESBETWEEN(DateDim[DateKey], DATE(2019, 1, 1), DATE(2019, 12,31)))
[image: 1st wrong Result]

2.

Σ LY = CALCULATE(SUM(KontobuchungenFact[UmsatzNegiert]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateDim[DateKey]))
[[image: 2nd wrong Result2]
3.

Σ LY = CALCULATE(SUM(KontobuchungenFact[UmsatzNegiert]), KEEPFILTERS(DateDim[M]), USERELATIONSHIP(DateDim[J], LetztesVollesJahrDim[AktuellstesJahr]), USERELATIONSHIP(DateDim[DateKey], KontobuchungenFact[StapelDateKey]))
[image: 3rd wrong Result]

Filters being applied on the page/visual:

- CompanyKey
- DateKey >= 2018-01-01 (page filter that limits the displayed rows in yearly matrix to the last 3 ys)
- Some other irrelevant keys

Visual configuration:

[image: Matrix's Visual Configuration]

Relations:

[image: Model relations]

Values/Rows in the LetztesVollesJahrDim table:

[image: LetztesVollesJahrDim MostCurrentFullYearDim]

Calculated Measures/Table in Tabular Editor showing the calculation of the "01 Jan" column of the first Matrix, which displays correct results:

[image: Tabular Editor Calculated Measure/Column "01 Jan"]

Impression of the Report:

[image: Overview]

So in summary I need a clue/DAX formula that recognizes the Monthes in each column and ideally uses the relations to the last year table trespassing the year's filter through DateDim to the Facts.

It is funny, that the upper matrix works, but not the one on the bottom. It is not possible to use the calculated measures approach of the first matrix in the last matrix because the performance would drop to > minutes calculation. So I cannot use the same approach and need a fast one.
Anybody an idea? :-)